# FreeNAS: How to increase scrub 'threshold'?

Tags: zfs, truenas, raidz

My NAS box is set to default scrub threshold every 35 days.

How do I change it to scrub every Saturday night?  Do I need to create a cron job?

I'm on FreeNAS-8.0.4-RELEASE-p2-x64 (11367)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that 8.0.4 does not support this. After upgrading to 8.2.x, there's a new `Scrubs` option where you can set the schedule.